# How does facebook detect Youtube, Vimeo, SoundCloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html, youtube

I need a script that detects a Vimeo, Youtube, Dailymotion, SoundCloud link and embed it right after pasting the link in a textarea just like facebook and google plus.

Is there anyway to do that, a plugin or something ?

I did a lot of research on google but I didn't find anything useful

Please help me guys

Comment: A. Your question is not clear, B. whatever I have understood its off-topic to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

[Embed.ly](http://embed.ly) can help you to do what you want. A tutorial for Embedly acting like the facebook textarea can be found [here](http://blog.embed.ly/post/45149989946/creating-a-facebook-like-url-submission-tool).

Also there is an PHP-Script which you could host yourself and call via javascript: [Embed](https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed).

I have not seen a script that mimics facebooks textarea. You will have to code this on your own!

Answer (score 0):

Use an onchange event to parse the text, if the newly added text is of URL syntax then you know you have a link. Then, if that link is to Vimeo, Youtube, Dailymotion, SoundButt do required embed process.

```
I do not help with code unless you show you have tried
```